# Find pixels with a certain color

Tags: php, image

Apart from looping through an images all pixels, are there any other algorithms one could use to find all pixels x- and y-cordinates in an image? Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to find all pixels with a given color you'll need to check every pixel in the image, otherwise the result may not be complete.